# Django validation error not working in Class Based View

Tags: python, django

I am using class Based view for update my Blog post but validation error message not showing in my Django template html. Here is my code:

**froms.py**

```
from .models import *
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


    class BlogPost(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
          model = Post
          fields = ['title','author','body']
          
          widgets = {
             'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
             'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
             'body': RichTextField(),
          }
          
          def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(BlogPost,self).clean() 
            title = cleaned_data.get('title')
    
          if title:
            if title(name)<30:
               count_text = len(title) 
               raise ValidationError("Title is too short")
```

**views.py**

```
class blog_update_view(UpdateView):
      model = Post
      template_name = "blog_update_post.html"
      form_class = BlogPost
```

**html**

```
 {% form.non_field_errors %}
                        
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.media}}
       
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button class="btn btn-info">Publish</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

I also want to know how to handle others error in **django-form** such as integrityerror in class based view.

Comment: In general, alternating between 4, 3, and 2 spaces to indent Python code is a disaster waiting to happen. Maybe look into using [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to automatically format your source code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not properly indented, you should place this in the scope of the `.clean(…)` method:

```
class BlogPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','author','body']
          
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'body': RichTextField(),
        }
          
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean() 
        title = cleaned_data.get('title')
        if title:
            if len(title) < 30:
                count_text = len(title) 
                raise ValidationError("Title is too short")
        return cleaned_data
```

But it makes more sense here to put in in the `clean_title` method, since then it is attached to the `title` field:

```
class BlogPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','author','body']
          
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'body': RichTextField(),
         }
          
     def clean_title(self):
         title = self.cleaned_data['title']
         if title and len(title) < 30:
             raise ValidationError("Title is too short")
         return title
```

A [**`CharField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) has a [**`min_length=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.min_length) that can be used:

```
class BlogPost(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        min_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','author','body']
          
        widgets = {
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'body': RichTextField(),
        }
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem I did indentation mistake in my Stackoverflow question but in my actual code I didn't make any indention mistake... Please see the question now

Comment: @boyenec: but it is still indented at the *same* level as `def clean`, it should be one indentation "deeper".

Comment: I know I can do it  by using  min_length in my model but I want to use it by def clean method

Comment: @boyenec: but `def clean` should only be overwritten for errors that are *not* field specific. If you raise an error with `clean_title`, then it will attach that error to that field, and thus you can show the error at the corresponding item.

Comment: @boyenec: furthermore using validators is typically a cleaner, since one can make *reusable* components that can fit in other fields as well.

Comment: exactly..I am typing less then 30 character in my title field but I am not seeing any error in my templates

Comment: I added this  {{form.non_field_errors}} in my html template for showing validation error but still now not working and not showing any error message

Comment: @boyenec: note that an empty string is acceptable according to your implemented logic. But regardless, then you should implement it in the `clean_title`.

Comment: I also used clean_title but still now not seeing any error message. see the screenshot1 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sbGDntZiG9SGVHtTkMCppApcRjnR4Zjt/view?usp=sharing screenshot2  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lr4gocuKVZiOuhiHVanhunHbtrfMrq6T/view?usp=sharing  in screenshot2  I type less then 30 character  but not getting any validation error message

Comment: @boyenec: you made a typo: it is `len(title) < 30`, not `title(name) < 30`.

Comment: sorry my mistake.. now I use it see the screeshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B09zax3nHti-BlKo0F-RlW9dPoJpkCYG/view?usp=sharing still now not seeing any validation error message

Comment: It's allowing user to type less then 30 charter title and publishing it

Comment: @boyenec: aarrrggghhh... You should *not* write this *inside* the `Meta` class, so outside the `Meta` class and inside the `BlogPost` class.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem  Thnaks.. for this little mistake I was straggling from 6 hours.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232186/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).